# Does an ArrayList require contiguous memory allocation (Java)

Tags: java, arrays, arraylist, abstract-data-type

Does an array or an ArrayList require contiguous memory allocation in Java? I understand that this is a fundamental question but I am finding conflicting information on the topic.

My intuition is that an array does not require contiguous memory allocation (since an array is just an address in memory so there is not much restriction on how memory is allocated after that address). To my understanding an ArrayList adds an extra constraint requiring elements to be arranged contiguously. Is that accurate?

I'm sorry if this has been asked before but I have not been able to find a direct answer. [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41929556/is-memory-contiguously-allocated-for-arraylists) is the closest I could find, but it adds a little more confusion saying that contiguous memory allocation with ArrayLists is JVM-specific, where I would think of contiguous allocation as the defining feature of ArrayLists.

Comment: The answer given there is accurate. But since anyone is free to write an alternative VM (such as GraalVM) it is also natural that it can't make claims for every VM. -- Btw, your intuition is a bit flawed. The array of pointers to objects is contiguous but bounded in JVM. And when the list grows, a new larger contiguous array is created somewhere else. Exactly as your linked answer describes.

Comment: *"... where I would think of contiguous allocation as the defining feature of ArrayLists."* - Given that the there is nothing in the `ArrayList` API (per the javadoc) that *forces* a (hypothetical) implementer to use a single contiguous backing array, it is not (technically) a defining feature.  Hence, the statement in the cited question that this is implementation specific is correct.

Comment: Indeed, I am not even sure that the JLS or JVM specs actually mandate that Java array shall occupy contiguous memory!

Comment: So the ArrayList is a list of pointers that are expected to be contiguous but may or may not be contiguous depending on the VM. Then is there a distinction between arrays and ArrayLists based on whether or not they store contiguous elements? The intuition I mentioned earlier is how it was first described to me but it seems like there is more to it.

Comment: @JeremyKievit An `ArrayList` is exactly what [its Javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/21/docs/api/java.base/java/util/ArrayList.html) says it is, nothing more, nothing less. Beyond that specification, implementation details may vary, between implementations, and between versions.

Comment: @StephenC No mention of contiguous memory in the *Java Language Specification* [page defining arrays](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se21/html/jls-10.html). Says only that an array contains a number of variables, with a fixed size, accessed by integer index values.

Comment: @JeremyKievit -  In summary, your intuition that `ArrayList` backing arrays use contiguous memory is correct *for implementations based on the OpenJDK version of `ArrayList` and HotSpot JVMs*. And probably for all other mainstream implementations as well.  But it is NOT correct for **all possible** JVM implementations.  That is what the linked Q&A says ... and it is correct.  (It is *moot* whether this an extant Java implementation where the backing array or arrays are not contiguous.)

Comment: Important distinction: on the OpenJDK JVM, ArrayLists use contiguous memory to store the _references to their contents,_ and the referenced objects can be scattered all around the heap.  There is no data structure in Java that ensures that specific objects, such as those in order in an ArrayList, are contiguously stored.